# JQuery Tools - Calling an Overlay with Text/Link - Using a rel attribute?

Tags: jquery, attributes, rel

I am using the JQuery tools located at http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html

I currently have this code below triggering the overlay

```
<div id="triggers">
<img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3651/3445879840_7ca4b491e9_m.jpg" rel="#mies1"/>
```

as you can see we are using the rel attribute to call the overlay with an image. I would like to call the overlay with plain text or a link.

At the very bottom of the page their is a script tag including this

> $(document).ready(function() { 
>   $("img[rel]").overlay(); });

I can provide any other information that may be needed. Thank you!

Comment: Try using <a href="#mies1">your text</a> and in the document ready use $('#triggers a').overlay() or similar and see if that moves you closer to what you want?

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<a href="#" id="makeOverlay">Overlay</a>
```

js

```
$("#makeOverlay").on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $("img[rel]").overlay();
});
```

Comment: I tried this code. "Overlay" does show up but when clicked it doesn't activate the overlay for some reason. Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: The first part is a standard link <a href>, the second is a piece of jQuery that will run the same code that is now being ran when your page loads, but when someone clicks the link instead. That's the best I could come up with without knowing more, maybe someone else has a better suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It can be called on link by following same that has been used for image:

```
<div id="triggers">
<a href="#" id="makeOverlay" rel="#mies1">Trigger Overlay</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { $("#triggers a[rel]").overlay(); });
```

'rel' attribute points to the id of the div which we want to open up as overlay

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you still need an answer but just needed to figure out something similar, and came up with

```
<a rel="#mies1"> Your text </a>

<div class="simple_overlay" id = "mies1"> Your overlay content</div>
```

And in your javascript section

```
$("a[rel]").overlay();
```

This works for me.